# Why does LineageOS 17.1 on Android maintain 2 mac addresses?

Tags: security, lineageos

I understand that LineageOS randomizes the phones wifi mac address - and thats fine.
But on analysis of the traffic from the phone, it seems to have 2 mac addresses simultaneously, and both are on the network. Only one of these is the reported 'wifi' mac address. I find this a little concerning.

Example:

```
192.168.1.14 - 3a:63:18:87:a4:f2 (Reported Wifi MAC in Lineage)
192.168.1.44 - da:d2:e4:56:10:94
```

Does anyone know what this second virtual interface is and why its there?

Hardware: Moto G7 plus
Version: Lineage_lake

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Lineage OS, but more of [Android's privacy using MAC randomization](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization)